# Correctly configure apache to work with a domain name

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, domain-name

I'm hosting my webserver (running Debian 8) at home and I have changed the default IP to my own and it worked.

I have since reinstalled my webserver to start from a clean slate, but it seems I have forgotten how to Google and/or configure so it will listen to my domain name. Everything works on the local network (192.168.X.X).

> This site can’t be reached
>
> domainname.nl took too long to respond.
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**What am I doing wrong and/or forgetting?**

This is my `conf` of my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domainname.nl

        ServerName domainname.nl
        ServerAlias www.domainname.nl

        Redirect permanent / https://domainname.nl/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domainname.nl

        ServerName domainname.nl
        ServerAlias www.domainname.nl

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.nl/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/domainname.nl/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/domainname.nl/logs/access.log combined

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/ssl/certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/ssl/certificate.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/ssl/cabundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

`a2ensite domainname.nl` has been executed and the `000-default.conf` has had a `a2dissite`. Everything in the `Apache2.conf` is still default, and `a2enmod ssl` is also done.

Comment: You don't mention how you have configured your server to be visible from the internet.  Have you forwarded ports or put nat rules in your router/firewall?

Comment: That might be it, @Paul! The firewall is UFW so I've configured that to do `SSH`, `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. I'm going to configure the router right now, if that's the bad-guy thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem thanks to [@Paul](https://superuser.com/users/89018/paul). I simply had to forward my ports in the router to the correct device. It changed addresses since it's previous install.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your primary NS server is not returning correct information about your domain:

```
ns0.nameserver.nl [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] returned an authoritative response in 109 ms:


Header

rcode:  Success
id: 0   opcode: Standard query
is a response:  True    authoritative:  True
recursion desired:  False   recursion avail:    False
truncated:  True
questions:  1   answers:    0
authority recs: 0   additional recs:    0
Questions

name    class   type
domainname.nl   IN  ANY
Answer records
[none]
Authority records
[none]
Additional records
[none]
-- end --
```

Also, check that your server is listening in the correct port/ip:

```
netstat -atun |grep -e 80 -e 443
```

Comment: `netstat -atun |grep -e 80 -e 443` returns the follwoing:
`tcp        0      0 192.168.2.6:80          192.168.2.254:64660     SYN_RECV
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 192.168.2.6:443         192.168.2.254:64661     TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 192.168.2.6:443         192.168.2.254:64662     ESTABLISHED` But it seems that forwarding ports in my router did the trick! Thank you nonetheless!